# How to override default CSS file location in a Qml Webview?

Tags: css, qt, webview, qml

How can I specify a default css file for a QML WebView in Qt 5.5? I am looking for a solution similar to the one provided by BlackBerry for their Cascades framework https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__websettings.html#property-userstylesheetlocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is currently not supported by the APIs provide by Qt 5